# CakePHP 3 - Add Middleware for common conditions on some endpoint

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm fairly new to CakePHP 3 and was wondering how I could achieve this. Basically I have a UsersController. This controller has a few basic RESTful methods and each of them checks for valid request method before proceeding.

For example

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function create()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post') === false) {
            throw new BadRequestException('This API endpoint only accepts a POST request');
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($this->request->data) || !count($this->request->data)) {
            throw new BadRequestException('No POST data received');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post') === false) {
            throw new BadRequestException('This API endpoint only accepts a POST request');
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($this->request->data) || !count($this->request->data)) {
            throw new BadRequestException('No POST data received');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post') === false) {
            throw new BadRequestException('This API endpoint only accepts a POST request');
            return false;
        }

        if (empty($this->request->data) || !count($this->request->data)) {
            throw new BadRequestException('No POST data received');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This looks rather repetitive and I think I could build a middleware that does all the request validation only for those methods (i.e. if I have index(), the middleware wouldn't apply); however I'm unsure on how this can be done.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Controller Initialize function for doing the common errors

```
public function initialize(){
    parent::initialize();

    if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new BadRequestException('This API endpoint only accepts a POST request');
        return false;
    }

    if (empty($this->request->data) || !count($this->request->data)) {
        throw new BadRequestException('No POST data received');
        return false;
    }

}
```

Also you can specify by method wise by using **$this->request->params['action']** like

```
if (!$this->request->is('post') && in_array($this->request->params['action'], ['index','add','delete'])) {
        throw new BadRequestException('This API endpoint only accepts a POST request');
        return false;
    }
```

Hope it will help you